# How to solve Error: Invalid hook call.ons:?

Tags: reactjs

I'v tried everything from stack overflow and it didnt work.Can someone tell me what's wrong?

Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See .. for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
// import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import './index.css';
import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';
import Header from './components/Header';
// import Footer from './components/Footer';

const routing = (
    <Router>
        <React.StrictMode>
            <Header />
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
            </Switch>
            {/* <Footer /> */}
        </React.StrictMode>
    </Router>
);

ReactDOM.render(routing, document.getElementById('root'));

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
// Learn more about service workers:
// serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Header.js

```
import React from 'react';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    appBar: {
        borderBottom: `1px solid ${theme.palette.divider}`,
    },
}));

function Header() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <CssBaseline />
            <AppBar
                position="static"
                color="white"
                elevation={0}
                className={classes.appBar}
            >
                <Toolbar>
                    <Typography variant="h6" color="inherit" noWrap>
                        BlogmeUp
                    </Typography>
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}

export default Header;
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
    
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

 export default App;
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "privatelessonapi",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "3.0.1",
    "@material-ui/icons": "3.0.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

the tree:

```
privatelessonapi@0.1.0 C:\Users\anatei\priapi-react\privatelessonapi
├─┬ @testing-library/react@11.2.7 invalid
│ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
├─┬ react-dom@17.0.2
│ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
├─┬ react-router-dom@5.2.0
│ ├─┬ react-router@5.2.0
│ │ ├─┬ mini-create-react-context@0.4.1
│ │ │ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
│ │ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
│ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
├─┬ react-scripts@4.0.3 invalid
│ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
└── react@17.0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi @anat please update your dependencies in package.json.
Everything else is working fine. I have tested your code.

```
 {
     "name": "privatelessonapi",
     "version": "0.1.0",
     "private": true,
     "dependencies": {
         "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.4",
         "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
         "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
         "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
         "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
         "react": "^17.0.2",
         "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
         "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
         "react-scripts": "3.4.3"
     },  
     "scripts": {
         "start": "react-scripts start",
         "build": "react-scripts build",
         "test": "react-scripts test",
         "eject": "react-scripts eject"
     },  
     "eslintConfig": {
         "extends": "react-app"
     },  
     "browserslist": {
         "production": [
             ">0.2%",
             "not dead",
             "not op_mini all"
         ],
         "development": [
             "last 1 chrome version",
             "last 1 firefox version",
             "last 1 safari version"
         ]
     }   
 }
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much !! but Iwm getting this error:

Comment: Failed to compile
./src/index.js
Attempted import error: 'Switch' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'.
This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.

Comment: I also found out that my insall npms of  react-router-dom and material-ui were not updated in json and node_modules localy. they were  installed in my c:users\anatei\node_modules.I think I must avoid insalling globaly ,but can't fix it...

Comment: npm uninstall -g <package_name>
remove it from global.. delete your package-lock.json and node_modules and run 'npm install' in a working directory with the updated package.json

Comment: Thank's a lot, but where do I run uninstall? my library is priapi-react/privatelessonapi/node_modules.

Comment: where to run install? my src is under privatelessonapi.

Comment: and lafter install, I must update package.json manualy??  I wish It would work.If It will I will be so gratefull. Thank you again !!!

Comment: I'v tried tried about everything. nothing seems to work. unistalled material-ui drom privatelessonapi, uninsalled react-router-dom from privatelessonapi. erased all node_modules that  were created.one under privatelessonapi and  one under priapi-react. erased json.lock. installed the packages back under priapi-react and got two jsons. one with only 2 dependencies of react-router-dom and the second of material-ui. erased that json and added manualy the dependencies to a json i had before under privatelessonapi. than I run npm start and nothin is working  :(

Comment: ok!! I'ts working!! I left the two package.json and everything is fine. thank you Is not enough. I hope You succeed in everything you do!!